# How to do performance testing for Power BI dashboard project using jmeter?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jmeter, powerbi

Since power BI request are not recording i was set up a profiler on the server and took the dax querys from the profiler and try to run it through the Jmeter. My questions are 
1) Can wedo performance testing using jmeter in power BI projects?
2) Can we connect to the Analysis services to run the Dax querys?

And when i m trying to connect to the Analysis services i m getting below error massage.
[image: connection error]

[image: Connection properties with values]

Comment: It says "Cannot open database".  We cannot tell you what's wrong other than the database is not responding.

Comment: Add more details about your database, did you forgot putting user name and password (in image) or you just don't want to disclose it? did you add jar for driver and where?

Comment: Hey Jim I m getting this error when uname and password "Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.)"

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're using wrong driver. Given `IntegratedSecurity=true` I think you're trying to login with current Windows user, therefore:

1. Remove JTDS driver from JMeter
2. Download [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)
3. Drop `sqljdbc42.jar` somewhere to JMeter Classpath
4. Drop `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file from `auth` folder of the JDBC Server installation to JMeter's "bin" folder (or somewhere under [Java Library Path](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp))
5. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar and the .dll up

Assuming everything goes well you should now be able to connect. Just in case check out [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about databases load testing.

Comment: I m getting same issue Thank you